# Homogeneous mix of two lists

Tags: python

I want to mix two lists in python of different length in the most homogeneous way.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

The merged list of a and b should result in

```
c = ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3]
```

Is there a pythonic way to merge these two lists which also works if len(b)/len(a) is not an integer?

Comment: When `len(b)/len(a)` is not an integer how do you want to mix the lists then? Also, if you have alreay tried anything, you should post that as well.

Comment: What about slice the longer list into two parts? Mix the first part with the other list and append the second (unmixed) part to the mixed list.

Comment: what should `a = [1, 2, 3, 4];b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` output?

Comment: How do you assess 'most homogeneous'?

Comment: What i had in mind when i was saying 'most homogeneous':
The lists have `m` and  `n` elements. if we think of it in a `x-y` plane and the perfect mixing would result in a straight line from (0,0) to (m,n). The algorithm should order the elements of both algorithms in a way that the squared difference of the chosen path to the straight line is minimal. This is my trivial idea of a homogeneous ordering. Better ideas are welcome!

Comment: @aem: Not sure about squared differences, but the other way I was thinking about this was the ordering of vertical and horizontal grid line crossings of a line from (0, 0) to (m, n); that's essentially the same thing as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to interpret homogenous mixing: suppose that the two lists have lengths m and n (respectively).  Place the elements of the first list on the subinterval [0, 1) of the real line, spaced evenly apart with a gap of 1/m between each one.  So we might place those elements at positions 0/m, 1/m, 2/m, ... (m-1)/m.  But there's some room for manoeuvre: we might also place the elements at positions x/m, (x+1)/m, (x+2)/m, ... for any x in the range [0, 1).  Do the same for the elements of the second list, placing them at distance 1/n apart from each other, so that all the elements are again contained in [0, 1).  Now to get the homogeneous mix of the two lists, read off all of the elements (from both lists) in exactly the order that they appear along the real line.  If the placement is such that elements from the first and second list exactly coincide at one or more points, give preference to the first list (say) every time that happens.

You can code this idea up relatively easily, and after a bit of simplification you end with something fairly short and elegant.  Here's a generator function which generates successive elements of the mixed list:

```
def mix_lists(l1, l2):
    """ Mix two lists evenly, generating the elements of the mixed list. """
    m, n = len(l1), len(l2)
    for i in range(m + n):
        q, r = divmod(i * n, m + n)
        yield l1[i - q] if r < m else l2[q]
```

This corresponds to the case where we've placed the elements of the first list as far left as possible within [0, 1), i.e., at 0/m, 1/m, ..., and the elements of the second list close to the rightmost possible position (so the first element is close to 1/n, the second to 2/n, etc.)  So within the freedom that we have, elements of the first list tend to appear earlier than those of the second.

Here's an example run in the case where one list has length a multiple of the other:

```
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdef', [1, 2, 3]))
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3]
```

And a couple of examples where this isn't true:

```
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefgh', range(12)))
['a', 0, 'b', 1, 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 5, 'e', 6, 'f', 7, 8, 'g', 9, 'h', 10, 11]
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4]))
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3, 'g', 4]
```

Now for a bit of variation, you can add an offset in the `divmod` call: that offset should be strictly in the range `0 <= offset < m + n`.  Adjusting the offset amounts to shifting the elements of one or other of the lists (but with the shifts constrained so that all the elements still lie within the interval [0, 1)). By varying the offset, we get all the possible "evenly-mixed" patterns.

```
def mix_lists(l1, l2, offset=0):
    """ Mix two lists evenly, generating the elements of the mixed list. """
    m, n = len(l1), len(l2)
    for i in range(m + n):
        q, r = divmod(i * n + offset, m + n)
        yield l1[i - q] if r < m else l2[q]
```

Here are some examples of the differences in mixing as the offset varies.

```
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4], offset=0))
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3, 'g', 4]
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4], offset=2))
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 2, 'd', 'e', 3, 'f', 'g', 4]
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4], offset=5))
['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2, 'd', 3, 'e', 'f', 4, 'g']
>>> list(mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4], offset=9))
[1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 'e', 4, 'f', 'g']
>>> mix_lists('abcdefg', [1, 2, 3, 4], offset=10)
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e', 4, 'f', 'g']
```

Choosing the maximum offset of m + n - 1 results in the second list being favoured over the first, while choosing an offset of around (m + n) / 2 will mean that we start with elements from the longer list, which works particularly well in the case that one list is exactly one element longer than the other:

```
>>> list(mix_lists('abcd', [1, 2, 3]))
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 2, 'd', 3]
>>> list(mix_lists('abcd', [1, 2, 3], offset=3))
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd']
>>> list(mix_lists('abcd', [1, 2, 3], offset=6))
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I'm still sitting here completely blown away. you sir need more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. I find the ratio `a:b`, expressed in lowest terms, of the length of the first list to the second list, then I build up lists by alternating blocks of `b` elements of the second list followed by `a` elements of the first:

```
import fractions
def mixLists(xs,ys):
    m = len(xs)
    n = len(ys)
    d = fractions.gcd(m,n)
    s = m//d
    t = n//d
    xslices = (xs[i:i+s] for i in range(0,m,s))
    yslices = (ys[i:i+t] for i in range(0,n,t))
    mixed = []
    for x,y in zip(xslices,yslices):
        mixed.extend(y)
        mixed.extend(x)
    return mixed
```

Typical output:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> mixLists(a,b)
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3]
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> mixLists(a,b)
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 'd', 'e', 'f', 3, 4]
```

If there is a nice ratio `a:b` between the lengths this function will return a list where consecutive slices of size `a+b` will have representative amounts drawn from each of the two lists. But -- the result isn't very homogeneous in the case where the lengths are relatively prime:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mixLists(a,b)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You need to think more carefully about what you want in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
def homogenized(bigList,smallList):
    ratio=len(bigList)/len(smallList) #integer division, needs to change for python 3
    smallList.reverse()
    counter=0
    out=[]
    for element in bigList:
        out.append(element)
        counter=counter+1
        if counter==ratio:
            counter=0
            try:
                out.append(smallList.pop())
            except IndexError:
                pass
    return out

print homogenized(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [1,2,3])
print homogenized(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], [1,2,3])
print homogenized(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], [1,2,3])



>>> 
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3]
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3, 'g']
```

The big list does have to come first. Wrap it in a check for a function robust to ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I am building on @Mark Dickinson's answer here.
I found the generator to be less understandable than a less performant version:

```
def mix_lists(l1, l2):
    """ Mix two lists evenly, generating the elements of the mixed list. """
    _l1 = [(i / len(l1), v) for i, v in enumerate(l1)]
    _l2 = [(i / len(l2), v) for i, v in enumerate(l2)]
    return [v for i, v in sorted(_l1 + _l2)]
```

I wouldn't introduce either version into a codebase without some explanations.
Great stuff Mark, totally made my day.

Answer (score -1):

If len(b)/len(a) is not an integer, then it's not even possible to properly distribute list.

This problem is more-like algorithm related not the coding part. To combine these two lists, you need to figure out pattern first. If there are x elements in a, and nx elements in b, then your list will be of length x+nx. It means for each element from a, there will be n elements from b.

So, firstly you need to find out this `n`, which can be done by finding out the ratio of length of lists. Then in an empty list, add elements in pattern 1 element from a, and n elements from b, and so on till you've all the elements in `c`.

Here is small Python program. You can modify it accordingly to suit your own preference.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

i,j = 0,0
diff = len(b)//len(a) # int value
c = [] # Empty
tot_item = len(b) + len(a)
while tot_item != len(c):
    c += b[i:i+diff]
    c += a[j:j+1]
    i += diff
    j += 1
print c
```

Output

```
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 3]
```